# How to get from sql query page id and retrieve it url and title

Tags: pages, wp-query, sql

*Conditions:*
Page have template, for example: **/* Template name: News */**

Explaining:

We have many pages, and one page with assigned template (/* Template name: News */).

I want on main page (index.php) retrieve page(News) url and title.

Comment: I think you're going to have to clarify your question a little.  It's very cryptic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to summarize what you want and answer:

> I want on main page (index.php) retrieve page(News) url and title.

So you have a "News" page that's using a specific template called "News" and you want to grab that page's ID, URL, and title to display on the front page, correct?

## Get a Page by Template

There is no built-in way to grab a page based on the template it's using.  Instead, you have to search for all pages based on a hidden meta value that matches your page template.  So, let's say your News template is named `news-template.php` in the theme, then you'd use the following code to get the *first* page that use that template:

```
$news_pages = get_pages( array(
    'meta_key'   => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'news-template.php',
    'number'     => 1
) );

$news_page = $news_pages[0];
```

Remember, since `get_pages()` returns an array, you have to *manually* select the first element of that array.  Now this `$news_page` object contains the content of your News page.

## Displaying Page Information

Now, inside your `index.php` page you can display this page's information by referencing the `$news_page` object.

- **Page ID:** `$news_page->ID`
- **Page URL:** `get_page_link( $news_page->ID )`
- **Page Title:** `$news_page->post_title`

Comment: Thaanks :) You helped me ;)